# Get connection ID from ServerSocket

Tags: delphi, tcp, serversocket, delphi-2007

I need to get connection ID from ServerSocket. By client I send text and I need to know which client sended text. Any ideas??

Comment: Please elaborate.  It is unclear exactly what you are looking for.  Sockets do not have IDs.  Other than connected IP/Port pairs, you have to track any other identifying information manually.

Answer (score 1):

```
procedure Tf_serveur.ServerSocket1ClientRead(Sender: TObject;
  Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Socket.RemoteAddress+'\>'+Socket.ReceiveText);``
  // Socket.RemoteAddress  is the client ip 
  // Socket.RemoteHost     is the client nameposte
  // Socket.receivetext    is the client text sinding
end;
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, but could you please add some explanation to your answer?

Comment: What is unclear about it? There are ServerSocket events, they tell you which client socket triggered the event each time, and those sockets can tell you the local and remote IP:Port pairs for their connections. This code is logging the remote (client) IP and sent text to a `TMemo` component. If you want something more meaningful, like a username, then you have to implement that yourself, such as by having the client send its username upon connecting, and you storing that somewhere you can retrieve it when needed, such as in the `TCustomWinSocket.Data` property.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking that he is referring to the handle of the socket

```
procedure TForm1.srvrsckt1ClientConnect(Sender: TObject;
  Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
  var connectedClientSockHandle : Integer;
begin
  connectedClientSockHandle := socket.Handle;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you should do is have each new connection (in the `onaccept` function) assigned to a unique ID (random letters/numbers) then every command sent from client->server will contain the unique ID of that client.